# IntelliJ broken text for properties values in Android project bug

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a weird bug in IntelliJ.

[image]

When I click on it, it shows correctly. When viewing all properties, it also shows correctly.

This is the only issue that I'm having with font/text in IntelliJ. 
I do not have this issue in Android Studio, only in IntelliJ.

Only fields that can have preset values seem to be broken. Custom values that are input by the user work correctly.

Comment: Bug report is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I've just posted it there as well.